# How to Adjust/Re-square 4' x 4' Concrete Slab

Tags: landscaping, concrete-block

I have an approximately 4' x 4'concrete slab outside the door to my garage, like a small porch or whatever (see pic).

Over the ~20 years life of the house it has moved, probably along with the dirt, downhill-ish about 6 inches or so.  One can easily see it is not square/centered with the door anymore, and I am looking for ideas as to how to lift or push or roll or whatever it back into, or at least closer to, original position.

The placement and surrounding landscaping make it a challenge to get any kind of hoist into place.  There is a 5"-6" holly tree trunk about 4 ' to right (i.e. not the one partially visible in pic attached) that *might* used as a brace for a jack approach.

Right now I am looking for suggestions, thoughts, concerns, other relevant discussion.  Thanks...

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8y9lz0qlzbnm0y/2020-04-24%2014.19.08.jpg

Comment: @blacksmith37: it's pretty much 48" x 48".  I agree the camera seems to be adding an optical illusion; either way it probably won't affect whatever engineering solution I finally settle, I suspect.  Also, it is 6" tall, and I believe just sitting on top of the soil surface.

I'll check about whether the outer concrete "frame" is separate/moves separately from the center.  I'll be pissed if it is :--)

Comment: My current thought for this is to dig out whatever helpful/needed, then push/mallet through some PVC pipe underneath in two or three places, then use that to either lift with, or push something more solid (maple dowel? metal bar?) through the pipe.  Unclear to me if four people lifting up on four corners like this can handle it, though?

Comment: Jack up, 4 flat 2x4's parallel to house under it, several 2" steel pipes perpendicular to the 2x4's, 4 flat 2x4's parallel to house on top of pipes, set down on upper 2x4's, roll slab over the distance you desire feeding new pipes in as you go, jack up, remove pipes and boards, set down into  place, send me beer !

Comment: Be sure the 2x4's are level. If you get a heavy object on rollers (or wheels, but rollers are the right thing here) it will go downhill. Assuming 48x48x6 inches is correct, you'll have about 1200 lbs to deal with. If its was not reinforced, it may crack when you jack it or move it, and then you can pour a new one in the right place...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look square or 4 ft wide. Two or 3 AC guys just moved a 3' X 4' X 3" thick concrete pad 100 ft to set the new compressor on . I didn't watch but the only equipment they could have used was a hand truck. A few years ago I re-leveled  about 25 ft of 30" wide, 4 to 5 " thick sidewalk in 6 ft sections. I used a few car jacks ( scissors type work best) , pry or wrecking bars and numerous brick and cinder blocks; I needed to raise one edge about 6". And shovels. It took several hours over 2 days, but good exercise. Your pad looks like the edges may not be integral with the center and may separate when a side is jacked up. I think the first step is to dig down and find out how thick it is and dig out the soil on the side to which you want to move it.